# override mediaelement.play in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

how do I override `MediaElement.Play()` Method in media element on wpf. is it possible? if not how do I get current state of the media element which media is playing or is it stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CanPause`.

```
if (mediaElement.CanPause) {
    //something playing
} else {
    //media element not playing anything
}
```

Comment: it not available at wpf. I think its only at silverlight

Comment: Ubhaya Kalanamiththa I just tested, works at WPF, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.canpause(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry man. my bad.